# Vue.js setting attribute based on nested properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm building a checklist app as a way to learn Vue.

I've got a nested object with no defined max depth, and I want to display a status on all items that is based on if the item itself is checked, and if (some of) its children are checked (if there are any).

I would like this to happen without an extra property in the object, since these items are going to be draggable and I would like it to update the status automatically after some items moved.

This is my data:

```
[{
   name: "item 1",
   checked: 0,
   items: [
       {
           name: "subitem 1",
           checked: 0,
           items: [ 
               //etc...
           ]
       },
       {
           name: "subitem 2",
           checked: 0,
           items: [
               //etc...
           ]
       }
   ]
}]
```

The app looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <checkin-list :checklist="items"></checkin-list>
</div>
```

The `checkin-list` components template looks like this:

```
<li v-for="item in checklist">                    
    <div :status="childstatus(item)">
        <input type="checkbox" :id="'check_' + index" v-model="item.checked">
        <label :for="'check_' + index">{{ item.name }}</label>
    </div>

    <checkin-list :checklist="item.items"></checkin-list>
</li>
```

The `childstatus` function takes an item and loops through all its children to check if some or all items are checked.

When I check an item on level 4, it only updates level 3 and 4; it doesn't bubble all the way to the top. I've tried to `$emit` the event to its parents, but I don't know how to force the childstatus to be recalculated on those items. I'm not sure if this type of event bubbling is correct here or if computed or watched properties can be helpful here.
I'm curious about what you would suggest here.

Comment: pass level name also through prop, your id might be having similar names clashing, as they are needed to be unique to work properly.

Comment: @Helpinghand thanks! These code examples are a really minified view of the actual code and I indeed use levels and unique id's for each item in order to create unique id's and keys.